# mat sort header cell extra width once there is a break line

Tags: angular, mat-table

I have this issue that when the text inside the mat sort header is too long and it breaks into 2 separate lines the arrow on the right gets pushed a lot and there does not seem to be padding/margin or anything that can push it other than extra width that is added to the sort header for no reason.

This is what expected to be the behavior:
[image]

and this is what I am getting when the title is too long and breaks into 2 lines:
[image]

I can't seem to find anyone who have gotten this behavior yet answer how to fix it. all help is appreciated

Comment: Use CSS to set the elements `whitespace` property to `nowrap`.

Comment: @DanielB It just makes the text not break but I do still need it to be 2 lines.